# How to debug [object ErrorEvent] thrown in angular/jasmine test cases

Tags: angular, testing, events, jasmine, case

In my angular application, we are using jasmine and karma for running test cases.
I have several components and it has their test cases written.
When I added a new component and wrote test cases they ran successfully when I ran through fdescribe.
When I run the whole test suit, I get [object ErrorEvent] thrown on some test case randomly. I don't see any issue with that test case.
When I comment that test which it failed for [object ErrorEvent], it gave me the same error on another test case.

I tried to go to DEBUG on KARMA window and see the console, it didn't give me any clue.
I tried running ng test --source-map=false, it didn't give me any clue.

1. Are they any other options to find which test case is exactly causing the issue.
2. While running ng test is there any option to know from which file the test cases are running, such that when failed I can go and look into the test cases in that file.

Comment: Is there anyway we can see one of the tests that is producing the error?

Comment: Provide the code in which you are failing the code

Answer (score 0):

Please check your angular version test with below commands :

**CLI v6.0.8 and above**

```
--source-map=false
```

**CLI v6.0.x early versions**

```
--sourceMap=false
```

**CLI v1.x**

```
--sourcemaps=false
```

For Shortcut might also work:

```
ng test -sm=false
```

**UPDATE:** Also please check your cli version and make sure its latest one. also please remove node_modules and run

```
npm install
```

Click on below link for open this issue :

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/7296